# For loop skipping columns in R

Tags: r, loops

I want to concatenate text across 20 columns of my dataset (`dat`), skipping all NA values.

For example, if the first row had "cat" in column 1, "dog" in column 2, and NA in column 3, I want to compile that as "cat dog" in a new column (`dat$results`). Here's what I have:

```
m <- ""

for(i in 1:20){
  if(!is.na(dat[,i])){
    m <- paste(m, dat[,i], sep = " ") 
  }
  else {
  next 
  }
}

dat$results <- m
```

The loop only runs up to column 3 (which is NA for my first row). Not a problem for that first row, BUT other rows that do have text in column 3 don't get that column compiled. What can I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just concatenate all the columns in one go and remove `na`'s and double spaces afterward

```
dat$result <- gsub('\\s\\s', ' ', gsub('NA', '', do.call(paste, d[,1:20])))
```